# How to inject the @request into a service?

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

When I try to inject the @request into any of my services, I get this exception:

> ScopeWideningInjectionException: Scope Widening Injection detected:
>   The definition "service.navigation" references the service "request"
>   which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either
>   move "service.navigation" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on
>   the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting
>   the service "request" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases
>   however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to
>   strict=false to get rid of this error.

What is the best way to proceed? Should I try to set this `strict=false` and how, or should I NOT inject the request service, but rather pass it to the service through my controller each time I call functions I need?

Other possibility would be to inject the kernel and take it from there, but in my service I  am using only @router and @request, so injecting the whole kernel would be irrational.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think there may have been some misunderstanding about what the official documentation says.  In most cases you do want to inject the request directly with a `scope="request"` attribute on the service element.  This makes the Scope Widening go away.

```
<service 
    id="zayso_core.openid.rpx" 
    class="Zayso\CoreBundle\Component\OpenidRpx" public="true" scope="request">
```

or in **yml**

```
zayso_core.openid.rpx: 
    class: Zayso\CoreBundle\Component\OpenidRpx
    public: true
    scope: request
```

It's only in specific special cases such as Twig extensions where you need to inject the container.

And kernel is not even mentioned in the page on scopes. Injecting the kernel is far worse (conceptually) than injecting a container.

UPDATE: For S2.4 and newer, use @Blowski's answer below.

Comment: This sounds interesting, I'm sorry, but could you rewrite that in YAML? I tried a couple of declarations like that (found on other sites), but I can't seem to make it right.

Comment: That works wonderfuly, in YAML it would be something like:
`service.sample: class: Company\SiteBundle\Services\Sample arguments: [@request] public: true scope: request`

Comment: are there any other values for scope? trying to run a service on from CLI

Comment: @PhillPafford the possible scopes are defined [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/scopes.html), but note that scopes for services are [deprecated in Symfony 2.8 and removed in Symfony 3](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-deprecating-scopes-and-introducing-shared-services).

Answer (score 103):

In Symfony 2.4, this has changed. Now, you can inject the 'request_stack' service.

For example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class MyService
{

    protected $request;

    public function setRequest(RequestStack $request_stack)
    {
        $this->request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

}
```

In your config.yml:

```
services:
    my.service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\MyService
        calls:
            - [setRequest, ["@request_stack"]]
```

Full documentation is here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Comment: +1 for that solution and link to appropriate symfony blog post.

Comment: The problem here is, this is executed after de constructor, so if you need request inside constructor this soluction is not complete

Comment: @K.Weber you can inject the `request_stack` into a constructor action, or indeed before the constructor is executed (say, in a `kernel.request` listener).

Comment: @Blowski if you inject request stack you should keep request stack in MyService and not request itself. And whenever you need a Request you call `Request#getCurrentRequest` (or `getMasterRequest`)

Comment: Injected @request_stack should be in apostrophes like '@request_stack' or it's invalid YAML

Comment: @webrama.pl: that is true, but only with Symfony 3.0 and later.

Answer (score 6):

**NB:** This answer was written back in 2012, when Symfony 2.0 was out and then it was the good way to do!

---

According to the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) it is usually not required to inject `request` into your services. In your service class you can pass `kernel` container (injecting it is not a big overhead, as it sounds), and then access `request` like this:

```
public function __construct(\AppKernel $kernel)
{
    $this->kernel = $kernel;
}

public function getRequest()
{
    if ($this->kernel->getContainer()->has('request')) {
        $request = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('request');
    } else {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    }
    return $request;
}
```

This code is also working fine when service is accessed in CLI (eg, during unit-testing).

Comment: Yes, that works. Just a little modification: Since `kernel -> getContainer()` returns a service_container, its better to inject it instead of the kernel (as the documentation stated). I already did `arguments: [@service_container]` and it works perfectly - no need to go through the kernel.

Comment: Quite wrong actually, with Symfony 2.1.x and a CLI command, `has` returns `true`, and the subsequent `get('request')` throws an exception.

Comment: @Gremo My answer was written almost a year ago and relevant for Symfony 2.0, so your downvote is not correct :)

Comment: You could just delete your answer, as it is hardly relevant :) Keeping SO clean :)

Answer (score 5):

The best way i found to make a service use the request service, not rely on the whole container and still not be required to have the request scope, was to make a RequestInjector service which takes the container. then you inject that into the service that wants to use the request object

```
class RequestInjector{

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container){

         $this->container = $container;
   }

    public function getRequest(){

        return $this->container->get('request');
    }
}

class SomeService{

    protected $requestInjector;

    public function __construct(RequestInjector $requestInjector){

        $this->requestInjector = $requestInjector;

    }
}
```

for services.yml

```
request_injector:
    class: RequestInjector
    public: false
    arguments: ['@service_container']

some_service:
    class: SomeService
    arguments: ['@request_injector']
```

Comment: I don't like this approach, you basically still inject the whole container at some point and use the Service Locator anti-pattern, you just don't know about it anymore. I don't see a benefit in that!

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The way I've found, and I'm sure it's probably not the best way (May not even be recommended), is to define the request service as synthetic.</strike>

*Edit: Indeed, this is not recommended, because it disables the scope sanity checks.*
This thread contains a good explanation of why Symfony is throwing that exception:
http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-devs/browse_thread/thread/a7207406c82ef07a/e2626c00f5cb9749

In your `services.xml`:

```
<service id="request" synthetic="true" />

<service id="my_service" class="......">
    <argument type="service" id="request" />
</service>
```

Per the **[docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#setting-the-scope-in-the-definition)**, it's better if you place your service in the request scope, or just inject the service container.

Comment: At this point, this might be better as a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use RequestStack directly, you could create a factory service that returns the current request using RequestStack.

```
# services.yml
app.request:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
    factory: [ @request_stack, getCurrentRequest ]
```

Then you can access the current request using the `app.request` service.

Answer (score 4):

another way to inject `currentRequest` directly:

setter injection:

```
calls:
     - ['setRequest', ['@=service("request_stack").getCurrentRequest()']]
```

or constrauctor injection:

```
arguments:
     $request: '@=service("request_stack").getCurrentRequest()'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more important to focus on getting the request instead of setting it. I would do something similar to @Blowski's solution, except using a getter. This is very similar to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#accessing-the-request-in-a-service)'s example.

```php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Newsletter;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class NewsletterManager
{
    protected $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    protected function getRequest()
    {
        return $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        // Do something with the request
    }
}
```

And your services.yml config file.

```
services:
    newsletter_manager:
        class:     Acme\HelloBundle\Newsletter\NewsletterManager
        arguments: ["@request_stack"]
```

Now you're always sure that you're getting the correct request, and you don't have to worry about setting/re-setting the request.

Answer (score -1):

As @simshaun states its best practice to place your service in the request scope. This makes the purpose of the service quite clear.

**Note** that this will make your service unavailable in other scopes such as the command line. However if your service relies upon the request, you should not be using it on the command line anyway (because there is no request available on the command line.