# Symfony 2 Service Parameters

Tags: php, api, symfony, instagram

One of the parameters I want to pass to a service when creating it is a result of a string calculation based on some user inputs. How can this be achieved automagically such that I do not have to pass the values into the object every time I want to access it from a different controller?

Just to illustrate I am adding the following example:

I have encapsulated the Instagram API in a Service by following the Documentation (brilliant), so writing `$instagram  = $this->get('instagram');` in my code **almost** works, as for the communication with the API I need to also set a callback URL, which I currently always have to do after the service is retrieved, for eg:

```
    $redirect_url   = $this->getRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost().$this->generateUrl('_instagram_authenticate_response');
    $instagram      = $this->get('instagram');
    $instagram->setApiCallback($redirect_url);
```

It is okay to do this once, but not in every freaking method I use when I talk to instagram. Please help :)

Update: My Service definition is as follows:

```
parameters:
    client_id: xxxxx
    client_secret: yyyyy

services:
    instagram:
        class: Clops\InstagramBundle\InstagramAPI
        arguments: ["%client_id%", "%client_secret%"]
```

The question is --> how do I pass the third parameter as a value generated in a controller? Or do I always have to do this via setValue(X) after I get the service?

Comment: Inject request and the url generator into your instagram service, not the controller.  I don't have an example handy but you could search for one.  Hence the comment and not an answer.  See item 1 in @forgottenbas's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but that is exactly what I want to find out how to do, as the official documentation is somewhat vague on this point :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a Dependency Injection issue.
As mentionned, you just have to pass `@router` and `@request` as a parameter of your service.

However, it seems a one-method only dependency so here's my way of thinking

You should create a `handleApiCallback` method which will be called immediatly after instanciation, in which you'll pass your `@router` and `@request`
This allows your class not to be strongly tied to Symfony

As a side note, you cannot pass directly `@request` as a parameter, you need to declare your service as [`request-scoped`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9332925/1607098)

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    instagram:
        class: Clops\InstagramBundle\InstagramAPI
        scope: request
        arguments:
            - %client_id%
            - %client_secret%
        calls:
            - [ handleApiCallback, [ @request, @router ] ]
```

<kbd>**Clops\InstagramBundle\InstagramAPI**</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class InstagramApi
{
    public function handleApiCallback(Request $request, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $host  = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
        $route = $router->generateUrl('_instagram_authenticate_response');
        $uri   = $host.$route;

        $this->setApiCallback($uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, there seems to be some kind of scope issue involved :( ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Clops\InstagramBundle\InstagramAPI::setApiCallbackFromSymfonyData() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, null given ... the request is not being passed to the class.

Comment: 1. Are you sure you added `scope: request` ? 2. Where did you call `$container->get('instagram')` from ?

Comment: Interestingly enough when moving the @router to a constructor parameter it works like charm :)

Comment: I have added scope, yes. The call is made inside a controller. I have moved the router and request variables to be parameters of the __construct method and everything is ticking correct now. Thank you very much for your help, really appreciated!

Comment: Anyone looking for a solution: full example can be found here --> https://gist.github.com/clops/6269005

Answer (score 0):

1. You can generate your parameter internally in service. In your situation you can pass `request` and `router` to service and make a work.
2. Make a base controller that will have method `getInstagram()`.

   ```
   public function getInstagram() 
   {
       $redirect_url = $this->getRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost().$this->generateUrl('_instagram_authenticate_response');
       $instagram = $this->get('instagram');
       $instagram->setApiCallback($redirect_url);
       return $instagram;
   }
   ```

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing... but do I then extend all my Controllers from this BaseController? And the BaseController in turn extends the standard Symfony Controller? Is this best practice? If so then I have guessed it right :D

Comment: And then again, this makes the usage of the service in other bundles anything but elegant :(

Comment: I failed to find any kind of link of how I could have a dynamic service container, thus my question :)

Comment: [Creating/Configuring Services in the Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container)?

Comment: That is right, but how do I pass $this->getRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost().$this->generateUrl('_instagram_authenticate_response'); as a parameter automagically?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of how I setup the service in the container.