# Make forms set data in session after validation

Tags: forms, session, symfony

I have the usual form after a POST:

```
$entity = new SomeEntity();
$form = $this->createForm(new SomeType(), $entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Instead of doing

```
if($form->isValid()) {
    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();
    $session->set('name', $entity->name())
    ...
}
```

Is there any way for the form to detect the validation and set the values in session if the validation passed?

It's too much logic I don't want leaked into the controller and it'll make my forms more reusable.

Comment: Your posted code well probably not work as expected.  Symfony 2 already has a session object,  $request->getSession().  Furthermore, tying the session to the form does not seem like the ideal design.

Comment: If you think there's a better way for keeping information between lots of forms please do suggest a better answer!

Comment: You could pass the `$request` object to the form and do `$request->getSession()` there. That's also a clear way of stating the form's dependencies.

Comment: An alternative design is to define repeated logic in services (that's what they are for). Then you can inject the service into the form and call the service there.

Comment: Post an example since it sounds like a better answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way in Symfony2 to detect validation.

Use form events to detect when data is being submitted, then do the validation and the rest of the logic.

`form.post_set_data` (`POST_SET_DATA`) or `form.post_submit` (`POST_SUBMIT`) are the best options. `form.post_submit` was `form.post_bind` prior to Symfony v2.3 .

Also check [this cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data) for more on form events in Symfony.

For example:

**The Form**

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Service\SomeService;

class SomeType extends AbstractType
{
     private $someService;

     public function __construct(SomeService $someService)
     {
         $this->someService = $someService;
     }

     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
     {
         // your form field declarations go here...

         $builder->addEventListener(
             FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
                  function (FormEvent $event) {
                      $form = $event->getForm();

                      if ($form->isValid()) {
                           $entity = $form->getData();
                           $this->someService->doSomething($entity);
                       }
                 }
          );
     }
}
```

**The Service**

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class SomeService
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

    public function doSomething($entity)
    {
        $session = $this->request->getSession();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('name', $entity->name());
    }
}
```

**Registering the service**

```
acme.demo.service.some: 
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\SomeService
    arguments: ['@request_stack']
```

Comment: Now that's just hawt. Thanks you so much! :O By the way, what's `$formModifier`?

Comment: It was a leftover from the code I copy/pasted from the Symfony2 docs for the example, so not necessary. I removed it.

Comment: After you suggested this I already had an idea but your suggestion is still better than what I had in my head. Thanks again! :)

Comment: For anyone reading this remember to use the request stack and not the `@request` service! http://stackoverflow.com/a/20502945/174368