# Symfony monolog after doctrine persist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to log all my users actions with monolog. But only if the actions persist data with doctrine, insert, update or delete.

What should I do ? Could I define a generic method like "afterPersist" to log every action ?

Thx !

EDIT :

The Listener :

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class DatabaseLogger
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $security_context;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, ContainerInterface $service_container)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->setSecurityContext($service_container->get('security.context'));
    }

    public function setRequest(RequestStack $request_stack)
    {
        $this->request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

    public function setSecurityContext(SecurityContextInterface $security_context)
    {
        $this->security_context = $security_context;
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        // configure this however you want
    }
}
```

and in service.yml

```
cc.listener.database_logger:
    class: Cc\HitoBundle\Listener\DatabaseLogger
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_listener, event: onFlush }
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: database_access }
    calls:
        - [ setRequest, [@request_stack] ]
    arguments: [ @logger, @service_container ]
```

I got an error when I add the security context :

> ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager", path: "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager -> doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection -> doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_manager -> cc.listener.post_persist -> security.context -> security.authentication.manager -> security.user.provider.concrete.user_db".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a listener with something like:

Build a listener:

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class PersistLogger
{
       public $logger;

       public function __construct($logger)
       {
           $this->logger = $logger; 
       }

       public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
       {
           // configure this however you want
           $this->logger->addDebug('whatever');
       }
}
```

Register the listener in `config.yml`

```
acme_mybundle.eventlistener.persistlogger:
    class: Acme\MyBundle\EventListener\PersistLogger
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
    argument: [ @logger ]
```

EDIT:
Injecting the security context into a doctrine listener causes a circular reference exception if you are storing your users in the database (e.g. with FOSUserBundle). This is because the security context needs to inject the entity manager so it can get users from the database, but because of the listener, the entity manager depends on the security context.

The workaround is to inject the whole service container (one of the only times doing this is justified), and get the security context from there:

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\EventListener;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface,
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

protected $service_container;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, ContainerInterface $service_container) 
{
    $this->service_container = $service_container;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function getSecurityContext() 
{
    return $this->service_container->get('security.context');
}
```

and

```
acme_mybundle.eventlistener.persistlogger:
    class: Acme\MyBundle\EventListener\PersistLogger
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
    argument: [ @logger, @service_container ]
```

Comment: Except for dot notation of services that you're not respecting ... all seems to be perfect +1

Comment: @DonCallisto updated it to dot notation so it really is perfect ;)

Comment: It's a joy for my eyes :D

Comment: Ok, that is what I want, but in the postPersist method, is it possible to get the user who persist the data ? And maybe extra informations like the route used ?

Comment: To get the route, you can inject the `request` service in the same way that you injected the `logger`. By *the user who persisted the data*, I assume you mean the currently logged in user? In that case, inject the `security context` service (`@security.context`), and get the user from there.

Comment: Instead of injecting `logger`, `request` and `security context`, can I use the `service container` to get all these services ?

Comment: @kyrillos yes that will work. But it's a good idea to inject services instead, because it makes testing and debugging easier, since you'll know at compile time whether you have a problem. If you inject the container and use `get`, then you'll only know at runtime. You can also take advantage of type hinting to ensure you are injecting the right service.

Comment: @kyrillos I couldn't find a canonical answer to why you shouldn't inject the service container, so I wrote one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931321/why-injecting-whole-service-container-to-another-service-is-almost-always-a-ba/26144509#26144509.

Comment: Sorry but I got an error :

The definition "cc.listener.post_persist" references the service "request" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either move "cc.listener.post_persist" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "request" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid of this error.

Comment: @kyrillos Here's one I answered earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20502945 Basically you inject the `request_stack` and get the actual request from there.

Comment: Hello, It isn't working in fact. Let see my edited question. Thx !

Comment: @kyrillos Oh I forgot about that. Unfortunately there's a long-standing problem in Symfony, where injecting the security context into a Doctrine event listener causes circular references. The workaround is to inject the service container (`@service_container`) and use `$service_container->get('security.context')` instead. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I still have an circular reference with my updated code !! Look above, I try to follow your instructions.

Comment: @kyrillos ok try that - I changed the setter to a getter. It's a kludgy fix but the alternative is really complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may have a look to [the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html), there is a very nice entry that talk about Doctrine's events.

In addition, you may have a look to the [method to create custom monolog chanels](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/channels_handlers.html).