# Symfony2: Getting user IP in custom authentication provider

Tags: symfony, authentication, ip

I'm creating my custom authentication provider and listener with Symfony. And also I need to implement IP ban on some unsuccessful login attempts. Thats the reason why I need to get it in the authentication provider where I check if credentials are valid. The problem is that I can't inject request service into it because I get "scope widening dependency injection exception". And getting IP address using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not a solution. Is there any other way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement the AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface on your Authenticator
This will provide a method onAuthenticationFailure where you can inject request.
Read more [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#handling-authentication-failure)

Answer (score 2):

have you tried setting this:

[How to inject the @request into a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332925/how-to-inject-the-request-into-a-service)

or in newer version using request stack:

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack