# How to inject @request_stack or @request in listener

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.7

I have this listener:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ControllerListener
{
    public function onKernelController( FilterControllerEvent $event, Request $request )
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType()) {
            $controllers = $event->getController();
            if (is_array( $controllers )) {
                $controller = $controllers[0];
                if (is_object( $controller )) {
                    if (method_exists( $controller, 'parControl' )) {
                        $controller->parControl(
                            $controller->getRequest(),
                            $controller->getRequest()->get( 'action' ),
                            $controller->getRequest()->get( 'context' ),
                            $controller->getRequest()->get( 'page' ),
                            $controller->getRequest()->get( 'case' ),
                            $controller->getRequest()->get( 'subset' )
                        );
                    }

                    if (method_exists( $controller, 'adminProjectControl' )) {
                        // to this method I need to pass Request $request  
                        $controller->adminProjectControl($request);
                    }

                    if (method_exists( $controller, 'accessControl' )) {
                        $controller->accessControl();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function onKernelResponse( FilterResponseEvent $event )
    {
        Utilities::flashDebugLoginMessage();
    }
}
```

And it's defined as a service at `services.yml`:

```
pdone.listener.preexecute:
    class: GroupDCA\PDOneBundle\Listener\ControllerListener
    arguments: [@request]
    public: true
    scope: request
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

But I should doing something wrong since I got this three errors:

> ContextErrorException in ControllerListener.php line 12: Catchable
>   Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   GroupDCA\PDOneBundle\Listener\ControllerListener::onKernelController()
>   must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
>   string given
>
> ContextErrorException in ControllerListener.php line 12: Catchable
>   Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   GroupDCA\PDOneBundle\Listener\ControllerListener::onKernelController()
>   must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
>   string given
>
> LogicException in bootstrap.php.cache line 3118: No listeners of the
>   "kernel.exception" event set a Response

So, how do I inject the Request to the listener? Can I do that? I have read also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332925/how-to-inject-the-request-into-a-service) post here but not get how to do this.

Comment: Each listener is passed 3 arguments - the event object being dispatched (`FilterControllerEvent`), the name of the event (`kernel.controller`) and the event dispatcher(`@event_dispatcher`) - this is why you are getting the error that the second argument is a string, as it's the event name. This can be useful if you want to chain event without needing to inject the `@event_dispatcher` into each listener/subscriber.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FilterControllerEvent` already [gives you access to the request](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/FilterControllerEvent.html#method_getRequest):

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();       

    // ...
}
```

If you need the request in listeners where event does not provide a request, always use [the request stack](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RequestStack.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class MyService
{
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Injecting a request is deprecated and will be removed. [Request stack is the way to go](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack). Don't use the `request` scope either.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing request object to the ControllerListener constructor from your service definition, not to the onKernelController method.

Instead do:

```
protected $request;

public function __construct (Request $request) {

    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Which should fix your problem and make the request object available.

Comment: Rather than injecting the `@request` service it is recommended to inject the `@request_stack` and then get the request via `$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()`. This also means that you don't need to change the scope of the service to `request`.

Comment: This is wrong. You shouldn't inject request directly as Qoop suggested. See my answer.