# Problems with Geoplugin in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony

I am trying to upgrading my existing Symfony 2.8 web site to 3.4.

I have faced and fixed many issues but I am stuck with a Geoplugin issue.

I have updated like the following my `AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` to respect the new YAML directives (thus I have added '' around @variables) :

```
app.ipgeo:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\Geo\Geoplugin
        arguments: ['@request', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@service_container']
        scope: request
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onLoad }
```

But I get a PHP Fatal error when accessing the web site :

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getUri() on string in /var/www/vhosts/alpclic-dev.fr/httpdocs/dev.scenes-locales.com/src/AppBundle/Utils/Geo/Geoplugin.php on line 58  

PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getUri() on string in
    /var/www/vhosts/alpclic-dev.fr/httpdocs/dev.scenes-locales.com/src/AppBundle/Utils/Geo/Geoplugin.php
    on line 58\n'
```

Any idea ?

Of course, it was perfectly working in 2.8 with the following configuration :

```
app.ipgeo:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\Geo\Geoplugin
        arguments: [@request, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @service_container]
        scope: request
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onLoad }
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory.

Comment: What do you recommend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so easy and "self-explanatory" !

I had to migrate to 'request_stack' service as mentioned here : [How to inject the @request into a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332925/how-to-inject-the-request-into-a-service)