# Symfony, API Platform custom operation Action, get Notice: Undefined property RequestStack

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired, api-platform.com

I'm using symfony 5 with API Platform to create Rest API.

I have an IIG entity and i'm trying to add a custom operation :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     shortName="iig",
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "calcul_score"={
 *             "method"="POST",
 *             "path"="/iigs/{project_id}/score",
 *             "controller"=ScoreAction::class,
 *             "swagger_context"={"summary"="GET IIG SCORE"},
 *         },
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={"get"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=IIGRepository::class)
 */
class IIG
```

Here is the Action script :

```
class ScoreAction
{

  private $requestStack;

  private $logger;

  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, LoggerInterface $logger)
  {
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }

  public function __invoke(IIG $data): IIG
  {
    $this->logger->info('About to find a happy message!');
    $projectId = $this->requestStack->query->get('project_id');
    dd($projectId);
  }
}
```

I'm getting

> Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack::$query

[image]

I tried to :

Add ScoreAction as a service with arguments and tags :

```
iig.calcul.score:
    class: App\Action\ScoreAction
    arguments: ["@request_stack"]
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Autoconfigure ScoreAction and make it public

```
App\Action\ScoreAction:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: true
```

I'm always getting

> Notice: Undefined property:
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack::$query

Comment: Probably depends on your Symfony version. Do you have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332925/how-to-inject-the-request-into-a-service. Maybe you can try $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest() to do something with the request.

Comment: RequestStack contains a set of request objects.  You need something like `$this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query...` Make sure you get the request in your method and not the constructor.

Comment: To see methods https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RequestStack.php

Comment: Might also try just injecting the request object directly into your method: `__invoke(Request $request, IIG $data)`.  I would think that would work.  In fact you could probably inject projectId as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, i should use $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->....